# Persistence.xml file usage without container [packaging]

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence, jpa-2.0

I am trying to use jpa/hibernate framework with a simple java console application without a container. According to jpa documentation the persistence.xml file should be placed under the folder META-INF on the src folder.

The issue came when trying to package the application as a simple jar file then the `persitence.xml` file will be within the jar file generated (since it should be placed on the src folder).

In this situation the `persistence.xml` file is not easy accessible to modify the application configuration like the DB URL, time out,the hibernate logs...

I tried to put the `META-INF/persistence.xml` outside the src folder and added it to the CLASSPATH but an error saying `Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath` is always thrown.

Is there any way to keep the `persistence.xml` editable and accessible once the application is packaged and deployed on production like any other classic configuration file (eg `.properties` files).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to make `persistence.xml` editable since you can provide additional properties when calling [`Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html) (or using similar Hibernate-specific mechanisms).

So, you can use `persistence.xml` for static configuration only, and configure dynamic properties using your own configuration mechanism.